# Sierpinski Layers

Tags: code-golf, fractal

Starting with `/\` you can create a [Sierpinski triangle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sierpinski_triangle) like pattern by adding a line beneath such that...

1. Any loose branch `/` or `\` splits again into two branches: `/\`.
2. Any collision of branches `\/` dies with nothing (but spaces) under it.

Repeating these rules yields

```
     /\
    /\/\
   /\  /\
  /\/\/\/\
 /\      /\
/\/\    /\/\
etc...
```

([Inspiration by ViHart](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e4MSN6IImpI&t=2m0s))

Write a program or function that takes in a positive integer N and prints the first N lines of this pattern to stdout, with no more leading or trailing spaces than necessary.

For example, if the input is `1` the output must be

```
/\
```

If the input is `2` the output must be

```
 /\
/\/\
```

If the input is `8` the output must be

```
       /\
      /\/\
     /\  /\
    /\/\/\/\
   /\      /\
  /\/\    /\/\
 /\  /\  /\  /\
/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\
```

And so on.

The code with the fewest bytes wins.

Comment: Can you please make it "fewest bytes" to avoid code compression shenanigans?

Comment: @xnor Changed .

Comment: I was literally about to post this. Meanie. :/

Comment: Where's the APL answer?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### GolfScript (42 bytes)

```
~,-1%1\{' '*\.2base{'  /\\'2/=}%n@.2*^}/;;
```

[Online demo](http://golfscript.apphb.com/?c=Oyc3JwoKfiwtMSUxXHsnICcqXC4yYmFzZXsnICAvXFwnMi89fSVuQC4yKl59Lzs7)

This exploits a well-known relationship between Pascal's triangle and the Sierpinski triangle.

Answer (score 6):

## CJam, <s>48</s> 46 bytes

```
li(_S*"/\\":T+\{_N@S+TW%/S2**" /"/"\ "f/:+T*}*
```

Simple recursive approach based on observations  1 and 2 in the question.

[Try it online.](http://cjam.aditsu.net/)

#### How it works

```
li(         " L := int(input()) - 1            ";
_S*         " A := L * ' '                     ";
"/\\":T+    " A += (T := '/\')                 ";
\{          " do L times:                      ";
  _N        "   push A, '\n'                   ";
  @S+       "   A += ' '                       ";
  TW%/      "   B := A.split(reverse(T))       ";
  S2**      "   A := '  '.join(B)              ";
  " /"/     "   B := A.split(' /')             ";
  "\ "f/    "   C := { X.split('\ ') : X ∊ B } ";
  :+T*      "   A := T.join(sum(C, []))        ";
}*          "                                  ";
```

---

## CJam, 51 bytes

```
li__2mL,1a\{2_@##)1$f*+}/<f{2b_"  /\\"2/f=@@,-S*\N}
```

I like this approach better, but it can't compete with the recursive one. Even after eliminating `2mL` (which results in at least O(2<sup>n</sup>) execution time), I'm still at 48 bytes...

This approach encodes `/\`'s as 1's and double spaces between them as 0's. Considering the resulting arrays binary numbers, we see that the configuration of the *nth* row corresponds to the *nth* integer larger than 1 that can be expressed as a product of different Fermat numbers (integers of the form **2<sup>2<sup>k</sup></sup>+1**).

#### How it works

```
li__2mL,1a         " push L := int(input()), L, R := range(log(L)/log(2)), A := [1] ";
\{2_@##)1$f*+}/    " for I in R: A += { a × 2**(2**I) : a ∊ A }                     ";
<                  " A := A[:L]                                                     ";
f{                 " for I in R: push L, I                                          ";
  2b_"  /\\"2/     "   push (B := base(I, 2)), B, S := [ '  ' '/\' ]                ";
  f=               "   for J in I: J := S[J]                                        ";
  @@,-S*\N         "   push (L - len(B)) * ' ', J, '\n'                             ";
}                  "                                                                ";
```

Answer (score 5):

## Python 2 - <s>140 139 127 122 121 118</s> 116

```
N=input()
b,V,m,n=' V/\\'
s=b*~-N+m+n
R=str.replace
while N:print s;N-=1;s=R(R(R(R(s+b,b+m,V),n+b,V),n+m,b+b),V,m+n)
```

Based on temporary string replacements (https://stackoverflow.com/a/8687380/3419103):

1. `/` > `V`
2. `\` > `V`
3. `\/` > `__` (2 spaces)
4. `V` > `/\`

Comment: `b*(N-1)+m+n` could be `b*~-N+m+n`

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman: Awesome! Now I got you, JavaScript! ;)

Answer (score 4):

## Javascript - 117 bytes

Minified:

```
T=n=>{S=' '.repeat(n-1);a='/\\';for(t=s=S+a+S;--n;t+='\n'+s)s=s.replace(/\\\//g,'  ').replace(/ \/|\\ /g,a);return t}
```

Expanded:

```
T = n => {
    S = ' '.repeat( n-1 );
    a = '/\\';
    for( t = s = S + a + S; --n; t += '\n' + s )
        s = s.replace( /\\\//g, '  ' ).replace( / \/|\\ /g, a );

    return t;
}
```

Sample Output (for `n = 20`):

```
                   /\                   
                  /\/\                  
                 /\  /\                 
                /\/\/\/\                
               /\      /\               
              /\/\    /\/\              
             /\  /\  /\  /\             
            /\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\            
           /\              /\           
          /\/\            /\/\          
         /\  /\          /\  /\         
        /\/\/\/\        /\/\/\/\        
       /\      /\      /\      /\       
      /\/\    /\/\    /\/\    /\/\      
     /\  /\  /\  /\  /\  /\  /\  /\     
    /\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\    
   /\                              /\   
  /\/\                            /\/\  
 /\  /\                          /\  /\ 
/\/\/\/\                        /\/\/\/\
```

Now if only the `repeat` and `replace` function names weren't so long. :P

Answer (score 3):

## Haskell, <s>128</s> 112

```
g n=unlines$take n$i t([1..n]>>" ")%(i(\l->l++l%i(t.t)(t l>>"  ")%l)["/\\"]!!n)
t=tail
(%)=zipWith(++)
i=iterate
```

Comment: If I count the characters I get 128 - also you forgot to `import Data.List` (since you used `unlines`), which brings it up to 145

Comment: @Flonk `unlines` is in the prelude.

Comment: Oops, maybe I should have looked that up before commenting. My bad!

Answer (score 3):

## Pyth, 45 bytes

```
K"/\\"Jt+*QdKVQpbJ=JjKsmcd"\ "cj*2dc+Jd_K" /"
```

#### Example run

```
$ pyth -c 'K"/\\"Jt+*QdKVQpbJ=JjKsmcd"\ "cj*2dc+Jd_K" /"' <<< 16
               /\
              /\/\
             /\  /\
            /\/\/\/\
           /\      /\
          /\/\    /\/\
         /\  /\  /\  /\
        /\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\
       /\              /\
      /\/\            /\/\
     /\  /\          /\  /\
    /\/\/\/\        /\/\/\/\
   /\      /\      /\      /\
  /\/\    /\/\    /\/\    /\/\
 /\  /\  /\  /\  /\  /\  /\  /\
/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\
```

#### How it works

```
                            # Q = eval(input())
K"/\\"                      # K = "/\\"
      Jt+*QdK               # J = (Q * " " + K)[1:]
             VQ             # for N in range(Q):
               pbJ          #     print(J, end="\n")
                            #
=JjK                        #     J = K.join(
    sm                      #         sum(list(map(lambda d:
      cd"\ "                #             d.split("\ "),
            c               #                                                .split(    )
             j*2d           #              " ".join(                        )
                 c   _K     #                                .split(K[::-1])
                  +Jd       #                       (J + " ")
                       " /" #                                                       " /"
                            #     ))))
```

Answer (score 3):

## Ruby, 90

```
f=->n{a=["/\\".center(2*n)]
2.upto(n){a<<a[-1].gsub("\\/","  ").gsub(/ \/|\\ /,"/\\")}
puts a}
```

### Explanation

- Input is taken as an argument to a lambda. It is expected to be an `Integer`.
- Use `String#center` to create a `String` `"/\"` with `n - 2` spaces on each side and put it into an `Array` (`a`).
- Add to `a` the last element of `a` with every occurrence of `"\/"` replaced with `"  "` and every occurrence of `" /"` or `" \"` replaced with `"/\"`.
- Use `puts` to print each element in `a` on its own line.

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (E6) 107 <s>106</s>

Edit: fixed byte count, made recursive.

Not much different from the other JS answer ... at least this one 'prints' the pattern as requested.
The core is replacing ' /' '\ ' with '/\' and all the rest with '  ' on each new line.

```
F=(n,o=t='/\\',b=' ')=>
  n--&&
    console.log(b.repeat(n)+o)|
    F(n,(b+o+b).replace(/../g,s=>s==b+b|s=='\\/'?b+b:t))
```

**Test** In FireFox/FireBug console

```
F(15)
```

*Output*

```
                  /\
                 /\/\
                /\  /\
               /\/\/\/\
              /\      /\
             /\/\    /\/\
            /\  /\  /\  /\
           /\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\
          /\              /\
         /\/\            /\/\
        /\  /\          /\  /\
       /\/\/\/\        /\/\/\/\
      /\      /\      /\      /\
     /\/\    /\/\    /\/\    /\/\
    /\  /\  /\  /\  /\  /\  /\  /\
```

Answer (score 2):

## Perl 5 - 56 bytes

\0's can be replaced by actual null byte characters

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -l
$p="/\\";$_=$"x~$_.$p,y/\0/ /,print,$p^="\0\0$p"for-<>..-1
```

It is using the fact that if you ignore leading spaces and represent '/\' as 1 and '  ' as 0 the pattern in a given row f(n) = f(n-1) ^ (f(n-1) << 1). However the calculations in the code above are executed on strings that are close to the expected output (no leading spaces, other spaces replaced by null bytes) thanks to perl's bitwise string manipulation.

```
$p="/\\";          # initialize
  $_=$"x~$_.$p,    # loop start, add spaces
  y/\0/ /,         # replace nulls with spaces
  print,           # output
  $p^="\0\0$p"     # calculate next string
for-<>..-1         # loop from -n to -1
```

Answer (score 1):

### Python 2, 84 bytes

```python
n=i=input()
while i:print' '*i+''.join("/ \ "[j&i+1>0::2]for j in range(n-i+1));i-=1
```

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica, 86 bytes

```
Column[Row/@Mod[Table[Binomial[n,k],{n,0,#-1},{k,0,n}],2]/.{1->"/\\",0->"  "},Center]&
```

Answer (score 0):

### Javascript with lambdas, <s>141</s> 128

**141**

```
f=n=>{for(a="25",q=0;++q<n;a=a[r='replace'](/^|$/mg,1)[r](/(.*)$/,"$1\n$1")[r](/..(?=.*$)/g,x=>x%3?11:25));return a[r](/./g,x=>"  /  \\"[x])}
```

**128**

```
f=n=>(t=a=>--n?t(a[r='replace'](/^|$/mg,1)[r](/(.*)$/,"$1\n$1")[r](/..(?=.*$)/g,x=>x%3?11:25)):a)("25")[r](/./g,x=>"  /  \\"[x])
```

Can be tested at Firefox (n=16):

```
               /\               
              /\/\              
             /\  /\             
            /\/\/\/\            
           /\      /\           
          /\/\    /\/\          
         /\  /\  /\  /\         
        /\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\        
       /\              /\       
      /\/\            /\/\      
     /\  /\          /\  /\     
    /\/\/\/\        /\/\/\/\    
   /\      /\      /\      /\   
  /\/\    /\/\    /\/\    /\/\  
 /\  /\  /\  /\  /\  /\  /\  /\ 
/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\
```

Answer (score 0):

## Python 2, 97 bytes

```
i=input()
x=1
while i:i-=1;print " "*i+bin(x)[2:].replace("0","  ").replace("1", "/\\");x^=2*x
```

Comment: Welcome to Programming Puzzles & Code Golf! Nice answer :D